# Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

A Jenkins file that I'm using from a community repo is failing. The owners of the repo say there's likely something wrong with my Jenkins build. Any thoughts on what would cause the error in this step? I have WORK_DIR defined as an environment variable in Jenkins Global configuration.

Error is:
Error when executing always post condition:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

````
      always { dir( "${env.WORK_DIR}" ) {
        cucumber reportTitle: 'Apickli test report',
              fileIncludePattern: '**/reports.json',
              jsonReportDirectory: "target",
              sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL',
              trendsLimit: 10
      } }```
````

Comment: Can you share your full pipeline? The cucumber plugin works for me with the latest version without any issue.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apigee/devrel/main/references/cicd-pipeline/ci-config/jenkins/Jenkinsfile

Comment: Does the pipeline work when you remove the post block?

Comment: No, looks like other steps rely on it as others end up failing.

Comment: post block is the last block that is executed in the pipeline and it's not dependent on other stages. The issue is not with the post block you shared above. Since there are so many dependencies in the pipeline, just doable to check whether everything is set properly.

Comment: jenkins should include the line in the WorkflowScript (the Jenkinsfile) in the stacktrace, that should help finding where it's failing.